# history.back() doesn't work in Safari on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, safari

My app is based on AngularJS 1.2.3. The application is enabled as a web app for iOS. The app contains back buttons with onclick handlers with the following code

```
history.length && history.back()
```

I've also tried using `history.go(-1)` as well. Problem is, the browser doesn't navigate back in history in Safari on iOS, or when the app is saved to the home screen as a web app. One thing i find weird however is that it works fine in Chrome on Safari, as Chrome actually is the Safari browser engine.

I know it have worked before, but doesn't anymore for some reason. The iPad is running iOS 7.0.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using AppCache history.back will not work on iOS7 (check http://www.sencha.com/blog/the-html5-scorecard-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-in-ios7/).

So if that's the problem, the easiest solution is to disable AppCache.

Comment: This iOS7 Safari bug appears to have been fixed in iOS 7.1.2, which is rolling out at the moment.  It just became available for my iPad and iPhone, and it has solved the back navigation problem for my offline cached app.

Comment: I have 7.1.2 and the error still occurs. I really hope for iOS 8.