# Why are history entries not entered in mobile safari when using the application cache?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, html5-appcache

When using the application cache in mobile safari, history entries are not created when the hash fragment is changed.  Why is this?

For instance, try the following.

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html manifest='test.manifest'>
  <h1>test</h1>
</html>
```

### test.manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# version: 1

NETWORK:
*
```

1. Visit the site.
2. Change the hash fragment.
3. Press the back button.

I expect to be returned to the original hash, but am not.  Instead the back button is either disabled or skips the first history entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Safari 7. Only known work around is disabling appcache.

See [history.back() doesn't work in Safari on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115678/history-back-doesnt-work-in-safari-on-ios)